# Как организовать выборку по дате в SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Как организовать выборку из таблицы по двум датам?

К примеру, есть таблица `persons` (см.вложение).
Как из таблицы, выбрать значения из полей `name`, `date1`, но при этом включать в ответ записи только с максимальной датой поля `date2`?

Мои попытки:

```
select p.name, 
    p.date1, 
    p.date2 
from persons AS p 
where p.date1 BETWEEN "09/04/2018 02:00:00" AND "09/04/2018 05:00:00" 
    AND p.date2 = (SELECT max(date2) FROM persons WHERE name = p.name)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть в ответе должен выглядеть так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Покажите свою БД в нормальном виде, скриншоты даже не масштабируемы. 2. Почему из примера ответа пропал Борис1? 3. Что уже пытались сделать?

Comment: 1. Исправил. 2. Да вы правы там ошибка. Должен был пропасть "Борис2" тот что за 2 часа. 3. Пока вот до чего дошел: select p.name, p.date1, p.date2
from persons AS p
where p.date1 BETWEEN "09/04/2018 02:00:00" AND "09/04/2018 05:00:00" 
AND p.date2 = (SELECT max(date2)
FROM persons
WHERE
name = p.name) Но пока не могу сообразить, как выбрать все варианты из поля "date1"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще довольно просто:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where p.date2 = (select max(p1.date2) 
                 from persons p1 
                 where p1.name = p.name 
                     and p1.date1 = p.date1
                 )
```

Comment: Нет, по этому запросу, ответ выглядит так же как и сама таблица...